# Issues with fstream pointer in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

The following code works fine in codeblocks using mingw, but fails in visual studio. Why?

```
fstream* __fstreamm = new fstream();
string _fileName="testing.log";
__fstreamm->open(_fileName.c_str(), std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
if(__fstreamm->fail())
{
    __fstreamm->open(_fileName.c_str(), std::fstream::trunc | std::fstream::out);
    __fstreamm->close();
    // re-open with original flags
    __fstreamm->open(_fileName.c_str(), std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
}
__fstreamm->seekp(0, ios::end);
*__fstreamm << "SSSSSSSSSTTTTTTTAAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRRRRTTTTTTTTTTT"<<std::endl;
__fstreamm->flush();
```

The file is created and written into when using codeblocks but when using vs2008 file is created but not written into.

Comment: First of all variables names starting with a double underscore are reserved for the implementation and are not to be used.  Second, why are you making an `fstream*` in the first place?

Comment: `fstream* __fstreamm = new fstream();` this is almost never the right thing to do.,

Comment: I use fstream* because I am implementing an array of fstreams to write into in another piece of code. In this example however it is irrelavent

Comment: I shall try removing the "__" from "__fstreamm"

Comment: You can still have your streams in a vector without using pointers.

Comment: @SergeyA I shall try that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
fstream* __fstreamm = new fstream();
string _fileName="testing.log";
__fstreamm->open(_fileName.c_str(), std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
if(__fstreamm->fail())
{
    __fstreamm->open(_fileName.c_str(), std::fstream::trunc | std::fstream::out);
    __fstreamm->close();
    // re-open with original flags
    delete __fstreamm;
    __fstreamm = new fstream();
    __fstreamm->open(_fileName.c_str(), std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
}
__fstreamm->seekp(0, ios::end);
*__fstreamm << "SSSSSSSSSTTTTTTTAAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRRRRTTTTTTTTTTT"<<std::endl;
__fstreamm->flush();
```